# Money supply M0 and M1 data for students

Tags: data-request, money-supply

Its my first time on economics xchange. I am a student of M.Phil. Economics 1st semester. I am writing a term paper and I need some data.

I am looking for money supply M0 and M1 data for top 50 countries (preferably in USD) for the year 2000. My university has a subscription of http://www.tradingeconomics.com/. But that is only accessible in the university's library.

I am back home for vacations. So I wanted to ask if anyone knows of a resource where this might be available for students free or at a low cost. Or if someone of you can provide this data. Thanks.

Comment: Anybody? I thought I was not looking hard enough. It seems it not that easy to find such data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't give up. Found these resources. They are free/cheap for data.

---

**For trade maps (between countries)**

http://www.trademap.org/Index.aspx

---

**This site is amazing. With more than 1k topics, you can almost get data for any topic by country/year. You can view the data on screen for free. But exporting the data would require a membership (currently at $29/month)**

https://knoema.com/atlas/topics/Economy

---

**This site also has an amazing database and covers a wide variety of topics. But I was unable to find data for M0 and M1**

http://databank.worldbank.org/data/reports.aspx?source=world-development-indicators#s_i

---

**An easy to use currency converter with the ability to find exchange rates back to January, 1990**

https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/

---

I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the best websites for this rather general economic data is

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/

On the first look I found money supply data for many countries. Additionally, you can check the websites of national central banks, which usually have comprehensive data, especially on monetary time series.